# jQuery Validation inside Bootstrap modal doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Ok so i'm trying to use jQuery Validation to validate my form inside modal. However, my jQuery Validation doesn't even fire at all, not even an error. I already used the debug, and there's a warning:

> Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing.

These are my codes:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Form Add Question Category</h4>
        </div>
        <form id="form_input" method="post" action="">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="hidden" id="submit_type" name="submit_type" value="address_insert"/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <label for="txtDeviceID">Device ID</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDeviceID" name="txtDeviceID" placeholder="Device ID"/>
                                    <div class="error_validation" style="color:red; font-size:9px;"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <label for="txtPassword">Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
                                    <div class="error_validation" style="color:red; font-size:9px;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <label>Employee</label>
                                    <select class="select2_employee" name="select2_employee" style="width:100%"></select>
                                    <div class="error_validation" style="color:red; font-size:9px;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <label>Branch</label>
                                    <select class="select2_branch" name="select2_branch" style="width:100%"></select>
                                    <div class="error_validation" style="color:red; font-size:9px;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="txtIPLocal">IP Local</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtIPLocal" name="txtIPLocal" placeholder="IP Local"/>
                                    <div class="error_validation" style="color:red; font-size:9px;"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="txtPortLocal">Port Local</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPortLocal" name="txtPortLocal" placeholder="Port Local" />
                                    <div class="error_validation" style="color:red; font-size:9px;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="txtIPPublic">IP Public</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtIPPublic" name="txtIPPublic" placeholder="IP Public"/>
                                    <div class="error_validation" style="color:red; font-size:9px;"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="txtPortPublic">Port Public</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPortPublic" name="txtPortPublic" placeholder="Port Public"/>
                                    <div class="error_validation" style="color:red; font-size:9px;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="txtIPAlternative">IP Alternative</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtIPAlternative" name="txtIPAlternative" placeholder="IP Alternative"/>
                                    <div class="error_validation" style="color:red; font-size:9px;"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="txtPortAlternative">Port Alternative</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPortAlternative" name="txtPortAlternative" placeholder="Port Alternative"/>
                                    <div class="error_validation" style="color:red; font-size:9px;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" value='Submit' class="btn btn-md btn-primary" >Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
var validate_start = $("#myModal #form_input").validate({
                debug: true,
                ignore: [],
                rules: {
                    txtDeviceID: {
                        required: true
                        //                        lettersOnlySpace: true,
                        //                        minlength: 5,
                        //                        maxlength: 15
                    },
                    txtPassword: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    select2_employee: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    select2_branch: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    txtIPLocal: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    txtPortLocal: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        range: [1, 65535]
                    },
                    txtIPPublic: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    txtPortPublic: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        range: [1, 65535]
                    },
                    txtIPAlternative: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    txtPortAlternative: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        range: [1, 65535]
                    }
                },
                //                messages: {
                //                    txtDeviceID: {
                //                        required: "Input required."
                //                    },
                //                    txtPassword: {
                //                        required: "Input required."
                //                    },
                //                    select2_employee: {
                //                        required: "Input required."
                //                    },
                //                    select2_branch: {
                //                        required: "Input required."
                //                    },
                //                    txtIPLocal: {
                //                        required: "Input required."
                //                    },
                //                    txtPortLocal: {
                //                        required: "Input required."
                //                    },
                //                    txtIPPublic: {
                //                        required: "Input required."
                //                    },
                //                    txtPortPublic: {
                //                        required: "Input required."
                //                    },
                //                    txtIPAlternative: {
                //                        required: "Input required."
                //                    },
                //                    txtPortAlternative: {
                //                        required: "Input required."
                //                    }
                //                },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    console.log("validate success!");
                    error.appendTo(element.siblings('.error_validation'));
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    console.log(form);
                    //                    $.ajax({
                    //                        url: $("#submit_type").val(),
                    //                        type: 'POST',
                    //                        dataType: 'JSON',
                    //                        data: function (params) {
                    //                            console.log("parameter");
                    //                            console.log(params);
                    //                            return JSON.stringify($(form).serialize());
                    //                        },
                    //                        //                        data: $(form).serialize(),
                    //                        success: function () {
                    //                            //                             $(form).html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    //                            //                             $('#message').html("<h2>Your request is on the way!</h2>")
                    //                            //                                 .append("<p>someone</p>")
                    //                            //                                 .hide()
                    //                            //                                 .fadeIn(1500, function () {
                    //                            //                                 $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/ok.png' />");
                    //                            //                             });
                    //                        }
                    //                    });
                    return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
                },
                invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
                    // 'this' refers to the form
                    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    console.log("error " + errors);
                }
            });
```

I've already tried many solution, from fixing the form inside modal body, use the unobstrusive library, but it still doesn't want to fire. Please help me, one lead to trigger the validation is enough, i will follow afterwards.

Thankyou.

Comment: You would need to add your validation rules inside something like the first example here, http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/ - replace `$('#myInput').trigger('focus')` with your code.

Comment: @TiesonT., thanks it has something to do with the late DOM creation, and more or less that link you gave me, gave me ideas to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to init the validation code right after the modal is shown. If you have something like $('#myModal').open(), then you have to init the validation after the open method. I believe it is something related to the DOM manipulation.

Comment: You're right! It's all about DOM manipulation that occured post modal show